# Can Copay iOS wallet sync with the Copay oSX wallet?

Tags: mac, ios

Can Copay iOS wallet sync with the Copay oSX wallet? Hoping to use the same wallet across both devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. Assuming you first created the wallet on your iOS and want to access it on macOS:

1) Open CoPay on iOS

2) Go to "Settings"

3) Under "Bitcoin Wallets" there's "Personal Wallet", click it

4) Choose "Backup" under "Security"

5) Write down the 12 words seed

On your macOS:

1) If you have just installed CoPay, it'll ask you for seed. You can type it, and then you're done.

If you already have CoPay installed:

1) Press "+" next to "Bitcoin Wallets"

2) Choose "Import Wallet"

3) Type your recovery seed